Opensearch connector is not working with apache flink
This is the Apache flink SQL query to create the dynamic table in the flink
report_type_os_sink_sql = """
    CREATE TABLE report_type_sink (
        `id` INTEGER,
        `uuid` STRING,
        `value` STRING,
        `label` STRING,
        `es_index_name` STRING,
        `sequence_number` INTEGER,
        `created_at` TIMESTAMP,
        `updated_at` TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY(id) NOT ENFORCED
    ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'opensearch',
          'hosts' = 'https://search-dev-000-reports-gizgrvlkkvi34pijqesj7fe5ju.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:9200',
          'index' = 'report_type_sink_flink',
          'username' = '<username-here>',
          'password' = '<password-here>'
    );
"""

I am using this jar file: `flink-sql-connector-opensearch-1.1.0-1.18.jar`
But while running it, Neither I am getting any error nor it can connect.
Even when I am giving the wrong host/username/password then also it does not throw any error.
While doing the sink via postgres-CDC connector from Postgres to Postgres for the same table, it is working fine, but from Postgres to OpenSearch this OpenSearch connector is not working properly, can anyone help me out here?
What wrong here in the above configuration? I am not able to solve it.
I tried with other connectors, still not able to solve it.
Thanks
